# Animate UIView transform happens instantly instead of over duration value

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to animate a view on screen in a similar way to how action sheets appear.

My router presents `CustomCardViewController` which has an overlay background.

After a short delay I'd like `containerView` too animate into view from the bottom.

Instead what is happening however is it just appears in place. There is no animation between the transition.

```
final class CustomCardViewController: UIViewController {

  private let backgroundMask: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .init(white: 0, alpha: 0.3)
    return view
  }()

  private lazy var containerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .red
    view.transform = .init(translationX: 0, y: view.frame.height)
    return view
  }()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    backgroundMask.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTapToDismiss)))

    modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

    [backgroundMask, containerView].forEach(view.addSubview(_:))

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      backgroundMask.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
      backgroundMask.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
      backgroundMask.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
      backgroundMask.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),

      containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 24),
      containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -24),
      containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -24),
      containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 200)

    ])

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0.33, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
      self.containerView.transform = .identity
    }, completion: nil)

  }
}

private extension CustomCardViewController {
  @objc func onTapToDismiss() {
    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to animate constraint ...

Comment: I'm confused, I can't just animate the `y` position?

Comment: Yes you can animate the Y position.

Comment: You’re triggering the animation early in the lifecycle. Instead of viewDidLoad, try to trigger it on the viewWill/viewDid appear.

Comment: Also make sure with the transform you’re applying you’re not making the constraints inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your animation block from another lifecycle method. You can't trigger this from `viewDidLoad` as the view has only loaded, there is nothing on screen yet.

Try using `viewDidAppear`

Answer (score 0):

For animation, you need to update the constant of the constrain that you want to animate. Here, since you're trying to animate from the bottom, you need to update a vertical constrain in this case, the bottom constraint. Here's the code for animation:

```
final class CustomCardViewController: UIViewController {
    //..
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // remove bottom constraint from here
        ])

        containerViewBottomConstraint = containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 250)
        containerViewBottomConstraint?.isActive = true
    }

    var containerViewBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint? // declare bottom constraint

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        containerViewBottomConstraint?.constant = -24

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 5, delay: 0.33, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```